# How can I add multiple IF OR statements in an excel?

Tags: excel, statements

I have to test a condition where the parameters can be more than one string. For eg: I would like to test

```
if (cell1="CA" or cell1="OR" or cell1="NV" or .....)` 
   print 1
else 
   print 0
```

How do I do this? Excel only allows me to check maximum of 2 values in an or statement like this -

```
=IF((OR(U11="CT",U11="ME")),1,0)
```

Can someone help me how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Excel [OR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/or-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0) is not restricted to two conditions.

```
=IF(OR(U11="CT", U11="ME", U11="XX"), 1, 0)
```

More succinctly as,

```
=--OR(U11={"CT", "ME", "XX"})
```

Comment: The { } array function like that only works with constants and cannot be other cell addresses/variable correct?